# Why does Linux allow up to 3 TLS segments per lightweight process?

Tags: linux-kernel

On x86, Linux sets aside 3 places in each process' LDT for TLS segments. After memory is allocated for thread-local variables, one or more of these TLS segments can be set using a `set_thread_area` syscall.

Comments in the Linux source (see `arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h`) say that the 1st one is used for TLS set up by libc and the 2nd is used for Wine's `%fs` Win32 support.

So why are there 3 segment descriptors set aside for TLS segments? Does anybody or anything actually use all 3?